# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processStagingDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-custom-view, retrolambda

I'm currently working on custom view and have the next issue.
I've created custom attributes and in case if I don't use enum everything is okay.

```
<declare-styleable name="GCSettingsItem">
    <attr name="gc_settings_item_type">
        <enum name="none" value="0" />
        <enum name="arrow" value="1" />
        <enum name="check" value="2" />
        <enum name="switch" value="3" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="gc_settings_item_text" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

But as soon as I add attribute with enum I get the next error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processStagingDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/volodiachorneknyy/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

What may be the reason for such issue?

**UPDATE 1**
I use retrolambda. I tried to do the same without it and everything is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of trying, I found the solution. Looks like **enum attributes can't have the same name as java keywords**. So right after I change **switch** to different word everything work good. Also, I tested it with class, enum, and other java keywords.

Comment: Enum values are typically uppercased, by the way

Comment: @cricket_007 I know about that, but in that case of android, all resources and attributes, including enums, are lowercased.

Comment: Ooh, my bad. Xml enums... Right... I thought you meant Java enums and I was thinking the code would have a compile error

Comment: @cricket_007 as I describe, compile error will be in case using keywords for enum name, which is a little bit strange as for me.